# python replacing a line in a file not working

Tags: python, replace

I have a JSON file named myBlock.json :

```
{
  "server": "https://abc.us",
  "name":"XYZ",
  "myData":"2019-04-08T15:43:05.810483Z",
  "someFlg":"T",
  "moreData":"k"
}
```

I am trying to change that with new date and time info so

```
        with open("myBlock.json") as json_data:
            self.myBlockInfo = json.load(json_data)

        origData = self.myBlockInfo["myData"]
        origLine = '\"myData\":\"'+origData +'\",'

        nowData = self.timeISO8601ZuluUTC()
        newLine = '\"myData\":\"'+nowData+'\",'

        with open("myBlock.json", "r+") as fh:
            for line in fh.readlines():
                if origLine in line:
                    print ("1-->", line)
                    str.replace(line, origLine, newLine)
                    print("2-->", line)
```

but not only the line is the same but also the file myBlock.Json stays the same and does not change?

Comment: You should read the file as a json string, load it into a dictionary, modify that dictionary with the new value, write the dictionary back to the file.

Comment: Yes I tried it but when I write it back all formatting is messed up

Comment: is what you posted the actual contents of the file? If so, that's not proper JSON

Comment: Could you post original and final *json* content? What you're trying to do here is a lame workaround (*gainarie*). I think it also qualifies for an *XY Problem*. If the file is a *json* read/write it as such.

Comment: I have edited and added more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you do not need to escape the double quote inside single quotes. I mean, use this instead:

```
origLine = '"myData":"'+origData +'",'
```

Then, an easier way to do the replacement is to replace the whole file content instead of reading line by line:

```
with open("myBlock.json", "r") as fh:
    oldcontent = fh.read()
    if origLine in oldcontent:
        print("found!!")
    newcontent = oldcontent.replace(origLine, newLine)
with open("newfile.json", "w") as fh:
    fh.write(newcontent)
```

But, this is not guaranteed to work! I put a `if` in the first `with` block to help you check if what you expect really exists. Chances are that, the input JSON can have spaces around the colon, like `"myData": "foobar"`, or even new lines arond the colon. Those are all legitimate JSONs. That's why some one in the comment suggested you to read the JSON, modify it, and write the JSON back.

If you think writing JSON back will messed up the format, try

```
 newcontent = json.dumps(modified_data, indent=4)
```

The `indent=4` will "pretty-print" your JSON by inserting appropriate indentation, likely retain some formatting you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the file on this way:

```
with open("myBlock.json", encoding="utf-8") as json_data:
    myBlockInfo = json.load(json_data)

origData = myBlockInfo["myData"]
origLine = '\"myData\":\"'+origData +'\",'

nowData = "asdsa"
newLine = '\"myData\":\"'+nowData+'\",'
myBlockInfo["myData"] = "sdfsd"
updated =  open("myBlock.json", "w", encoding="utf-8")
json.dump(myBlockInfo, updated)
```

Editing the `myBlockInfo["myData"]` block directly and the save the file with json.dump. Also, you can use the encoding option to make sure both encodings, when read and write are the same

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I had done but the format of json block changes. and becomes one complete line .   {
  "server": "https://abc.us", "name":"XYZ", "myData":"2019-04-08T16:43:05.810483Z",
  "someFlg":"T",
  "moreData":"k"
}

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the ***indent*** *kwarg* of [[Python 3]: json.**dump**(*obj, fp, *, skipkeys=False, ensure_ascii=True, check_circular=True, allow_nan=True, cls=None, indent=None, separators=None, default=None, sort_keys=False, **kw*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump):

> If *indent* is a non-negative integer or string, then JSON array elements and object members will be pretty-printed with that indent level. An indent level of 0, negative, or `""` will only insert newlines. `None` (the default) selects the most compact representation. Using a positive integer indent indents that many spaces per level. If *indent* is a string (such as `"\t"`), that string is used to indent each level.

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import json


def main(argv):
    with open("in.json") as inf:
        obj = json.load(inf)

    print("Original date:", obj["myData"])
    # Modify obj["myData"] to whatever you need (self.timeISO8601ZuluUTC())

    output_indent = int(argv[0]) if len(argv) and argv[0].isdecimal() else None
    with open("out.json", "w") as outf:
        json.dump(obj, outf, indent=output_indent)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main(sys.argv[1:])
    print("Done.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q055578224]> sopr.bat
> *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code.py
> in.json
>
> [prompt]> type in.json
> {
>   "server": "https://abc.us",
>   "name":"XYZ",
>   "myData":"2019-04-08T15:43:05.810483Z",
>   "someFlg":"T",
>   "moreData":"k"
> }
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Original date: 2019-04-08T15:43:05.810483Z
> Done.
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code.py
> in.json
> out.json
>
> [prompt]> type out.json
> {"server": "https://abc.us", "name": "XYZ", "myData": "2019-04-08T15:43:05.810483Z", "someFlg": "T", "moreData": "k"}
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py 2
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Original date: 2019-04-08T15:43:05.810483Z
> Done.
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code.py
> in.json
> out.json
>
> [prompt]> type out.json
> {
>   "server": "https://abc.us",
>   "name": "XYZ",
>   "myData": "2019-04-08T15:43:05.810483Z",
>   "someFlg": "T",
>   "moreData": "k"
> }
> ```

As you can see, the file has been nicely rewritten without the need of modifying its raw (text) contents.